# AWS Spring Integration: Error Channel Eample

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am looking for the example of how to use the error channel from the set up:

```
  SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
     new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(sqs, "queue");
  adapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(1);
  adapter.setWaitTimeOut(20);
  adapter.setTaskExecutor(task);
  adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
  adapter.setErrorChannel(...);
```

I am not sure how the error channels work and did not find much about it online.

Answer (score 0):

If the downstream flow throws an exception, an `ErrorMessage` containing the failed message and cause are sent to the error channel. See [Error Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler).